# php error logging: replacement for deprecated errcontext in error_handler in 7.2.0

Tags: php, error-handling

Version 7.2.0 deprecated an highly useful bit of information for debugging in error_handler: the errcontext (the 5th parameter) values, which gave the value of variables in the scope of the error.  Without that I can get only the file, line and error message, but that doesn't help if the error is a result of the actual values being processed.  So the question is: "is there a way to get the values of the variables in a post 7.2.0 world?"

For background, I am using the Larry Ullman (famous php author) custom error handler, but I can no longer use the 5th parameter ($e_vars), below.

======

```
function my_error_handler ($e_number, $e_message, $e_file, $e_line, $e_vars) {
global $live, $email_errors;
$message = "An error occurred in script '$e_file' on line $e_line: \n<br />$e_message\n<br />";
$message .= "Date/Time: " . date('n-j-Y H:i:s') . "<br />";
$message .= "<pre>" . print_r ($e_vars, 1) . "</pre><br />";
if ($live) { // Don't show the specific error.
    error_log ($message, 1, $email_errors,"From:errors@domain.com"); // Send email.
    // Only print an error message if the error isn't a notice.
    if ($e_number != E_NOTICE) {
    echo '<div id="Error">A system error occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience.</div><br />';
    }   
} else { // Development (print the error).
    echo '<div id="Error">' . $message . '</div><br />';
}
```

}

```
set_error_handler ('my_error_handler');
```

======

Comment: Never knew that existed before now. I created my `set_error_handler` without it, I can still collect global variables like $_POST, $_GET, etc. and in practice it's provided enough context for me. However, if you *really* wanted (but not recommended), I suppose you should define some of your variables as globals so they are accessible to your function.

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to get the $_POST and $_GET values.  That's what I am missing by losing the errcontext.  Can you share you method of capturing those values?

Comment: Just use them directly. Since they are global variables they accessible to all your functions.